# add Chip inside TextField with multiline props doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I would like to insert my tags in TextField with multiline.
something like this

[image]

**But** I have this behavior

- tags don't return to new line
- tags are in the middle of the TextField

[image]

the following is the code i'm using.

```
<TextField
          value={inputValue}
          margin="dense"
          rows={6}
          multiline
          fullWidth
          placeholder="add tags"
          sx={{mt:2}}
          label="tags"
          InputProps={{
            startAdornment: selectedItem.map(item => (
            <Chip
              key={item}
              tabIndex={-1}
              label={item}
              onDelete={handleDelete(item)}
              style={{height:"100%"}}
            />
            )),
            onChange: event => {
              handleInputChange(event);
            },
            onKeyDown: handleKeyDown
          }}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

well, here's a solution; I had to give a style to `InputProps`

```
<TextField
      value={inputValue}
      margin="dense"
      fullWidth
      placeholder="add tags"
      sx={{mt:2, pb:4}}
      label="tags"
      InputProps={{
        //added style
        style: {display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap', gap: "10px"},
        startAdornment: selectedItem.map(item => (
        <Chip
          key={item}
          tabIndex={-1}
          label={item}
          sx={{mt:2}}
          onDelete={handleDelete(item)}
          style={{height:"100%"}}
        />
        )),
       
        onChange: event => {
          handleInputChange(event);
        },
        onKeyDown: handleKeyDown
      }}
    />
```